# How would you Post to Google Blogger from your website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, blogger, google-code

Im working on a small business website dashboard and want to include a feature allowing the user to post to their blogger blog directly from their independent website dashboard - eliminating the need to go to the blogger website. The form would simply be a text field and post button. I realize that some sort of authentication will be necessary so this needs to be included in the solution in some way. I know that you can post to a blog via a registered email address.

Would this be a simple mailto form? Does anyone know of a script that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Blogger has an API for this, that's pretty straightforward.

http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#CreatingPublicEntries

Forms with `mailto` actions are generally a bad idea - they're not globally supported and a lot of people use webmail these days, too.